# SQL Query : Update from a select result

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-update

Here's my sql query

```
UPDATE dbo.TD_TOTAL_ACCOUNTS SET Total_Accounts = Total 
SELECT annee, mois,[Group],
(
 SELECT SUM(Accounts_Number) 
FROM olap.TD_ALL_ACCOUNTS 
WHERE EOMONTH(cast( cast(mois as nvarchar(2))+ '/' + '01'  + '/' + cast(annee as nvarchar(4)) as DATETIME)) <= EOMONTH(cast( cast(T2.mois as nvarchar(2))+ '/' + '01'  + '/' + cast(T2.annee as nvarchar(4)) as DATETIME)) AND [Group] = T2.[Group]
) AS Total 
FROM olap.TD_ALL_ACCOUNTS AS T2
```

The "Total" column is not recognized. I can't manage to name the table resulting from the select T3 and use it in the SET "Total_Accounts = T3.Total"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` and your code could will fail/produce wrong results. I strongly discourage to create `DATE` like that. Consider using `DATEFROMPARTS`.

Comment: lad2025 can you please explain more ?

Comment: **[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/451877?opt.textResults=true)** Please check how behaves concatenated `DATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (change IdColumn to your row identifier), though I strongly urge you to take Lad2025 comment into consideration.

```
UPDATE t 
SET Total_Accounts = Total 
FROM dbo.TD_TOTAL_ACCOUNTS t 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT IdColumn, annee, mois,[Group],
(
 SELECT SUM(Accounts_Number) 
FROM olap.TD_ALL_ACCOUNTS 
WHERE EOMONTH(cast( cast(mois as nvarchar(2))+ '/' + '01'  + '/' + cast(annee as nvarchar(4)) as DATETIME)) <= EOMONTH(cast( cast(T2.mois as nvarchar(2))+ '/' + '01'  + '/' + cast(T2.annee as nvarchar(4)) as DATETIME)) AND [Group] = T2.[Group]
) AS Total 
FROM olap.TD_ALL_ACCOUNTS AS T2
) T3 ON(t.IdColumn = T3.IdColumn)
```